# Parse a gzipped csv/tsv file

Tags: nim-lang

I'm starting to use the `parsecsv` module (https://nim-lang.org/docs/parsecsv.html), and I was wondering if there's an easy way to seamlessly (same procedure for both plain text and compressed files) allow to parse gzipped files as well.

How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just realized that `parsecsv` supports (of course) streams, so the library `zip/gzipfiles` can be used to open the stream.

```py
import parsecsv
import zip/gzipfiles

let str = newGzFileStream(filename)
    parser.open(str, filename, separator = sep)
    while readRow(parser):
       ...
```